# hostname attribute in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In the below docker-compose file,

```
dbc:
  image: mysql:5.6
  hostname: db
  expose:
    - "3386"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: somebackenddb
    MYSQL_USER: user1
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: pswd
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pswd

agent:
  image: somedockerhub/ansible
  volumes:
    - ../../whatever/x.yml:/whatever/y.yml
  links:
    - dbc
  environment:
    PROBE_HOST: "db"
    PROBE_PORT: "3306"
```

---

we are using `hostname` attribute in `dbc` service.

`agent` service is linked to that `hostname` whose value is `db`

Generally, hostnames are given to virtual machines.

---

Every container is given an IP address, but,

For a container launched by `dbc` service, what does `hostname` mean for a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[By default](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) hostnames of a docker container is equal to their container id.

Defining attribute `hostname: db` in docker-compose file will set hostname of `dbc` service container to be `db`.

If you enter the created container with `docker exec -it [container_id] bash`

and run command `hostname` you should see `db`.

Running `hostname -i` would show virtual ip address.

`cat /etc/hosts` would show:
...
`172.17.0.4      db`

Env. variable HOSTNAME insider container would equal `db`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617998/docker-compose-why-agent-app-service-fail-due-to-hostname